# Metric / Measure / Indicator / Statistic

Tags: analysis, statistics

I'm struggling with when to use each of these terms. I think in different areas of maths they are used with slight technical differences. Then there are further differences when being used "in the real world" (socially). The first comparison to spring to mind lies between analysis and statistics.

In analysis, a metric is a function $f:X \times X \rightarrow \left[0,\infty \right)$ but in statistics a metric (perhaps informally) seems to be used as a function on a sample $f:X^n  \rightarrow \left(-\infty,\infty \right)$. For example, the arithmetic mean.

I've heard of the arithmetic mean, geometric mean, etc being a 'metric' on some data set; I think technically it should be a statistic or a measure?

And then to confuse matters further, informally we hear terms such as KPIs (key performance indicators) or in the trading world, we have indicators like Bollinger bands. Are these statistics, measures or metrics?

Also, when Google or Youtube show 'metrics' on a channel is this the correct terminology?

I'm interested in both the technical differences and social differences. In short, if I perform some calculations on some data to end up with a number or group of numbers that help me make sense of the data, what have I just created?